# How to use plural with phalcon multilingue plugin

Tags: php, phalcon, multilingual

I use the phalcon translate plugin,
I have two files fr.php and en.php, containing an array with different key values.

For example `$messages = array("Familyname"=> "Nom","Firstname"=> "Prénom");`

But for the same word I need to have the singular and plural, how can I do this?

For example I've `array("company"=>"company")`, and if I have more than one company I want to have `"companies"`and not `company`.

For now if I want to have this result I must create two key `"company"`and `"companies"` is there an other way to have this result?

Comment: Realistically no - natural languages have so many exceptions and quirks that the only way to ensure that what you're saying is correct, and sounds correct, is to do it by hand - so you'll need both the *company* and *companies* translations.

Comment: The best solution is to avoid the test server side if > 1 then I take the plural key. Does Phalcon implement a method like i18n node.js plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n#i18n__n ?

Answer (score 0):

Could there be any other option than just use the Translation Matrix Array? Somehow, that seems to be the most likely option you have for now except if you prefer to gamble. If you chose the gambling option, you might try this:

```
function pluralize($translatedString, $lang="en"){
    switch($lang){
        case "en":
            $rX         = "#[yY]{1}$#";
            $pluralForm = (preg_match($rX, $translatedString)) ? preg_replace($rX, "ies", $translatedString): "s";
            break;
        case "fr":
            $pluralForm = "les {$translatedString}s";
            break;
        case "de":
            $pluralForm = preg_replace("#(.)$#", "en", $translatedString);
            break;
        default:
            $rX         = "#[yY]{1}$#";
            $pluralForm = (preg_match($rX, $translatedString)) ? preg_replace($rX, "ies", $translatedString): "s";
            break;
    }
    return $pluralForm;
}


var_dump( pluralize("Company", "en") );   //<== YIELDS  string 'Companies' (length=9)
var_dump( pluralize("Societé", "fr") );   //<== YIELDS  string 'les Societés' (length=13)
var_dump( pluralize("Firma", "de") );     //<== YIELDS  string 'Firmen' (length=6)
```

**A BIG NOTE:**

Never rely on this Function to give you the Precise Plural form of the Singular Noun. Whereas for English, this may be Ideal, it is up to you to see how (and if) to make it spit out the reasonable Plural for other Languages. However, as mentioned earlier, using the Translation Matrix would be the way-to-go in this Scenario....

Comment: What about *fish* ? ... or *sheep* ?

Comment: @CD001 **LOL** That was why there is the **BIG NOTE** below the Post....  and the Point was also emphasized that this is a Gambler's route... and should be avoided at all cost, except when one somehow feels up to it.....